# What is the relationship between Vishnu and Narayana according to different Vaishnavite sects?

Tags: vishnu

I have seen claims that

"narayanaya vidmahe vasudevaya dhimahi | tanno vishnuh pracodayat"

makes them identical.

Do different sects like Iyengars,Madhwas and Gaudiyas have different views on this?

Comment: They are all the same; literally synonyms. However, Gaudiya Vaishnavas think that Vishnu is an incarnation of Krishna, whereas the other Vaishnava sects believe it's the other way around.